# Information on this keypad

Tags: keypad

I receieved this 4x4 keypad in an electronics kit, but don't know what the pins (it has 2x5 pins), are, and can't seem to find a data sheet for it.

[image]

Any info or help is appreciated!

Comment: Without the datasheet, you can always test keypad connections by using your multimeter (switch it to connectivity test and point your probes to to output pins and try press the buttons, the output pins are normally connected to a row or a column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the following keywords in a search engine> 4x4 keyboard 10 pin
One quickly finds several solutions.

Confirm that it matches your pinout using an ohm-meter or by following traces.

[image]

Located here with software http://www.mikroe.com/eng/downloads/get/1215/keypad_manual_v100.pdf